# Print all open tabs in a Chrome window

Tags: google-chrome, printing, automation, browser-addons

I have to print frequently a couple of dozens of PDF pages open in one Chrome window. The manual process involves Cntrl+P for print; hit ENTER to proceed with the pinting; press Cntrl+DwnPg to go to the next tab and repeat the process again.

Can be this whole process automated?